# mapping by code in nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I'm examin some mapping examples which uses mapping by code, and I have one simple question
If I have two properties which are mapped like this

```
Property(x => x.UserName, m => 
        {
            m.Length(50);
            m.NotNullable(true);
        });


Property(x => x.UpperUserName, m => 
        {
            m.Length(50);
            m.NotNullable(true);
            m.UniqueKey(“UniqueUpperUserName”);
            m.Access(Accessor.Field);
        });
```

What this `m.Access(Accessor.Field);` means?

And why it's used on these second property UpperUserName and not in the first one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that NHibernate won't use the property itself when reading and writing values, but the underlying field.

```
// This will be used
var string upperUserName;

public string UpperUserName
{
    get { return upperUserName; }
    // Maybe this is a read-only property, 
    // so we must allow NHibernate to update the value somehow
    // set { upperUserName = value; }
}
```

You can read more on available access types in [NHibernate documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-property). Just scroll down to Access and Naming strategies tables.